# Not Running Second elseif Statement - Powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am having problems getting this script to run both statements. I have to run the script twice for this to work. When I run once it does the first statement and installs driver. But it doesn't do the second. But when I run it again then it does the second. Any help would be appreciated. Also please forgive my script not being well written. I know I can do this with less code too. I am learning and flying by the seat of my pants. Here is the script below:

```
$devicesTwo = Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | Where-Object{$_.ConfigManagerErrorCode -ne 0} | Select-Object -Property CompatibleID 
$devices = Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | Where-Object{$_.ConfigManagerErrorCode -ne 0} | Select-Object -Property HardwareId 
$unknown_Dev = $devices
$unknown_Dev_Two = $devicesTwo


 ForEach($ProblemDevice in $unknown_Dev) {

    $ProblemDevice.HardwareID[0]
 
    $test = $ProblemDevice

    } 

 ForEach($ProblemDeviceTwo in $unknown_Dev_Two) {

    

    $ProblemDeviceTwo.CompatibleID[0]
 
    $testTwo = $ProblemDeviceTwo

    } 


#Get List of Drivers from Folder
$folderWithDrivers = "C:\Users\Tech\Desktop\Drivers"
#Collect driver info
$drivers = Get-ChildItem $folderWithDrivers -Include *.inf -Recurse
#$drivers | Select Name 

 forEach ($device in $drivers){
       
      $found = Get-Content $device

       if ($found | Select-String $test.HardwareID -SimpleMatch) {

           pnputil /add-driver $device /install


        }
        

        elseif ($found | Select-String $testTwo.CompatibleID -SimpleMatch) {
            
            pnputil /add-driver $device /install

        }

        
        else {
       
    
            Write-Host "Not Found"

        }
        }
```

Comment: That's because your first condition is met, therefore it doesn't run the rest. `If` this is met, don't run anything else. If it's not met, go onto the next condition: i.e `elseif`. If that is met, run that code inside the scriptblock and nothing else. If neither your first `if`, or your second `elseif` is met, the `else` block runs for anything that the conditions didn't meet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment. . . here's some quick scripting that may work for you.

```
# Assign folder folder path that contains drivers to variable
$Divers_Path = "C:\Users\Tech\Desktop\Drivers"

# Get a listing of all .inf files in my Drivers folder.
$Driver_Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Divers_Path -Filter '*.inf' -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Get all unknown devices
$UNK_Devices = Get-CimInstance -Query "Select Name,CompatibleID,HardwareID From Win32_PNPEntity Where ConfigManagerErrorCode != 0"
    foreach ($Device in $UNK_Devices) 
    {
        $MaxCount = ($Device.HardwareID.Count, $Device.CompatibleID.Count | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
            if ($MaxCount -ge 1) {
                # Something here. Preferably a verbose message:)
                for ($i=0; $i -lt $MaxCount; $i++)
                {
                
                    $HWID_Found_Match = try { Select-String -Path $Driver_Files -Pattern $Device.HardwareID[$i] -SimpleMatch } catch { }
                        if ($HWID_Found_Match) {
                        
                            foreach ($File in $HWID_Found_Match.Path) 
                            {
                                PNPUtil.exe /Add-Driver $File /Install
                            }

                        }
                        else {

                            # no matches $HWID found

                        }

                    $CID_Found_Match  = try { Select-String -Path $Driver_Files -Pattern $Device.CompatibleID[$i] -SimpleMatch } catch { }
                        if ($CID_Found_Match) {

                            foreach ($File in $CID_Found_Match.Path) 
                            {
                                PNPUtil.exe /Add-Driver $File /Install
                            }

                        }
                        else {

                            # no matches $CID found

                        }

                }
            }
            else {

                "No matches found for:$($Device.Name)"

            }

    }
```

It would honestly benefit you a little more to use a `switch` statement instead but, this will do. As to your question, like mentioned in my comment, only the first condition that is met will run:

```
$One = 'one'
    if ($One -eq 'One') {
        # Condition is met.
        # Only run this block of code.
        'One Found'

    }
    elseif ($One -eq 'One') {
        # Condition is met but, so was the 1st "if", so this
        # will not Run.
        'One Found Again'

    }
    else {
        # This runs if none of the top conditions are met.
        'anything'

    }

# result:
# One Found
```

Whereas a `switch` statement run all blocks of codes where the condition is met unless specified to stop (`break`).

```
$One = 'one'
    switch ($One) {

        'one' { "I ran Once" }
        'one' { "I ran twice" }
        'Two' { "Two"}
        'three' {'Three' }

    }
# result:
# I ran Once
# I ran twice
```

You could technically switch out everything inside the `for` loop to just this:

```
                    $Found_Matches = try   { Select-String -Path $Driver_Files -Pattern $Device.HardwareID[$i],$Device.CompatibleID[$i] -SimpleMatch } 
                                     catch { try { Select-String -Path $Driver_Files -Pattern $Device.HardwareID[$i] -SimpleMatch } catch { Select-String -Path $Driver_Files -Pattern $Device.CompatibleID[$i] -SimpleMatch } }

                        switch ($Found_Matches) 
                        {
                            { $_ -match $Device.HardwareID[$i] }   { $_.Path}
                            { $_ -match $Device.CompatibleID[$i]}  { $_.Path }
                        }
```

*Excuse the ugly `try` and `catch` blocks, as it was the only way to silence the errors I was getting.*

Comment: Wow thanks for all the detailed info Abraham. Appreciate the time you spent. I was thinking about using a switch but was not sure how to implement it into my script. Is it possible to use a switch with If statements? Do I replace my if statement with it ? Could you give me an example and incorporate it in my code? Or is it complicated?

Comment: Hello, try the edited code, fixed some mistakes. Regarding the use of the switch statement, I meant in what you were trying to do. The code above should work just fine without it, so no need to implement it unless you'd like some cleaner looking code.

Comment: Hi. I did try that edited code but it keeps looping and just trying to install everything inside the drivers folder.  And yes I would like some cleaner code with the Switch statement but for now I just was curious to see how it would be implemented with the code I have. No biggie though.

Comment: See the edited code snippet for the switch statement. Can you try opening up a new instance of powershell and trying it again? Or if you're using the ISE, or an IDE, try it with a new tab. Seems like there is some old memory still loaded causing that loop. It should only do what's found.

Comment: Hi. I tried that and still it keeps looping. It does eventually stop but still only does one driver. The message in the loop is "Driver already exists, already in system". Just keeps looping that till it stops.  Would you mind showing me how you would add some of the changes to my script? That would help me understand more.  If you have time of course.

Comment: I'm a little confused, the message is saying that it's already installed. You can comment out the actual execution of the code and then just see what it's actually doing, so: `# PNPUtil.exe /Add-Driver $File /Install` and then: `$Device.HardwareID[$i]; $File; sleep 10`. This should allow you to see what drivers are correlated with what inf file. From the sound of it, there's nothing wrong.

Comment: ah I see. It keeps trying to install the drivers that are missing over and over. About 30 times. And then installs them. I got them to install now.  Not sure why its doing that?  I would show you if I could. Does it have something to do with the Maxcount statement?  If so could you explain what thats for?

Comment: The `$MaxCount` variable is so you don't do unnecessary looping through each property. Since the properties *HardwareID* and *CompatibleID* don't always contain the same amount of values, if we can just calculate which property has more and iterate through both just once, it's not as computationallly  expensive. So in the variable, we only get the **Max Count** of the property with the most values, and use that for our `for` loop.

Comment: So in other words, it should only do each value **once**, not multiple times.

Comment: oh I see. that does sound important for this scenario. I will look more into the MaxCount variable you made and try to understand it more. I really appreciate all the help. thanks!

Comment: one more thing. The script works but I wanted to show you the looping I was talking about.  It keeps looping the same driver over and over (about 30 times) and then finally installs it. Then it goes to the next driver and does the same thing and then installs it.  Here is an example of the loop for one of the drivers. 
Adding driver package:  e1d68x64.inf
Driver package added successfully. (Already exists in the system)
Published Name:         oem2.inf
Driver package is up-to-date on device: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_15B8&SUBSYS_15B81849&REV_00\3&11583659&0&FE

Comment: Unfortunately, that would be something you have to figure out on your end since I can't see your screen. Whatever is populated in `$Device.HardwareID` and `$Device.CompatibleID`, is what it will try to install. First it tries to locate the files using `Select-String`, so if that returns a bunch of the same .inf files, that's something different.

Comment: Think of it like this: 1.) Gather the HardwareIDs. 2.) Search for files that contain that string name from HardwareIDs and save them to a variable. 3.) Install all found files. So in other words, if `$Device.HardwareID` only has 2 values in it, for each value find every single file in your driver's folder that contains that HardwareID that you're currently iterating through. So it could possibly find 10 of the same thing and try installing them, which will give you that message that it's already installed.

Comment: ok thanks. I understand. You have already helped so much. Again appreciate it!!